# JLabel Text not Showing, JFrame Freezing on Wait

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm writing a rock paper scissors GUI application and in one of my `JPanel`s, I have a `JLabel`. This `JLabel` is supposed to say Rock for one second, then Paper for one second and then Scissors for one second. It's so far only showing the `JLabel` text for Shoot at the end. I can't seem to figure out why. Can anyone help?

Code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class RockPaperScissorsShoot {
    public JFrame shootFrame;
    JPanel shootPanel;
    JLabel shootLabel;
    int flagThing = 0;

    public RockPaperScissorsShoot(Window gameWindow) {
        shootFrame = new JFrame();
        shootFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        shootFrame.setSize(250, 150);

        shootPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        shootFrame.add(shootPanel);

        shootLabel = new JLabel();
        shootPanel.add(shootLabel);

        shootFrame.setVisible(true);

        shootFrame.setTitle("Rock!"); // the title changes
        shootLabel.setText("Rock!"); // but the JLabel text does not

        waitForMilSecs(1000);

        shootFrame.setTitle("Paper!");
        shootLabel.setText("Paper!");

        waitForMilSecs(1000);

        shootFrame.setTitle("Scissors!");
        shootLabel.setText("Scissors!");

        waitForMilSecs(1000);

        shootFrame.setTitle("Shoot!");
        shootLabel.setText("Shoot!"); //Except here, right here, the text shows up
    }

    public static void waitForMilSecs(long ms) {
        long checkMS = System.currentTimeMillis() + ms;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= checkMS) {
            System.out.println("Not yet!");
        }
        System.out.println("NOW!");
    }
}
```

Edit: I've tried adding a `SwingWorker` to handle the waiting in a separate thread. I still get a frozen GUI. Code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.*;
//import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker.StateValue;

class RockPaperScissorsShoot {
    public JFrame shootFrame;
    JPanel shootPanel;
    JLabel shootLabel;
    int flagThing = 0;

    public RockPaperScissorsShoot(Window gameWindow) {
        shootFrame = new JFrame();
        shootFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        shootFrame.setSize(250, 150);

        shootPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        shootFrame.add(shootPanel);

        shootLabel = new JLabel();
        shootPanel.add(shootLabel);

        shootFrame.setVisible(true);

        changeText(false, "Rock!", shootLabel, shootFrame, 1);
        changeText(true, "Paper!", shootLabel, shootFrame, 1);
        changeText(true, "Scissors", shootLabel, shootFrame, 1);
        changeText(true, "Shoot!", shootLabel, shootFrame, 1);
    }

    public static void changeText(boolean wait, String text, JLabel shootLabel, JFrame shootFrame, long secondsToWait) {
        while (wait) {
            wait = waiter(secondsToWait * 1000);
        }
        shootFrame.setTitle(text);
        shootLabel.setText(text);
    }

    private static boolean waiter(long ms) {
        boolean keepGoing = false;
        SwingWorker sw1 = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(ms);
                // String res = "Finished Execution";
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(get().toString());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        // executes the swingworker on worker thread
        sw1.execute();

        while (sw1.getState() != StateValue.DONE) {
            System.out.println("Not done (debug)");
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
        return false;
    }

    public static void waitForMilSecs(long ms) {
        long checkMS = System.currentTimeMillis() + ms;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= checkMS) {
            System.out.println("Not yet!");
        }
        System.out.println("NOW!");
    }

    public static void wait(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error waiting, cannot wait lol");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why my GUI is freezing still?

Comment: That's weird. For me, the window is white until the last JLabel text change.

Comment: I used this code: https://justpaste.it/5d6xu on repl.it compiler and it works fine

Comment: @ATP I just ran it in the repl.it editor and it has the same problem I originally described: https://repl.it/@JOSIAHWHITLOCK/11#Main.java

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried adding a SwingWorker into it, but I still get the same issue. What part of the program would I get the SwingWorker to do?

Comment: It's not so much a `SwingWorker` as a Swing `Timer` that code needs, to replace the `waitForMilSecs(long)` method. It will need a 'single shot' `Timer` for each of the 3(?) parts..

Comment: Okay, thank you! I ended up just getting rid of my while loop and using a callback, but I'll check out the timer when I refactor it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Swing] [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).
Try the following.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class RockPaperScissorsShoot implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame shootFrame;
    private JPanel shootPanel;
    private JLabel shootLabel;
    private int flagThing = 0;
    private Timer timer;

    public RockPaperScissorsShoot() {
        shootFrame = new JFrame();
        shootFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        shootFrame.setSize(250, 150);
        shootPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        shootFrame.add(shootPanel);
        shootLabel = new JLabel();
        shootPanel.add(shootLabel);
        shootFrame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String text;
        switch (flagThing) {
            case 0:
                text = "Rock!";
                break;
            case 1:
                text = "Paper!";
                break;
            case 2:
                text = "Scissors!";
                break;
            case 3:
                text = "Shoot!";
                break;
            default:
                text = null;
        }
        if (text != null) {
            shootFrame.setTitle(text);
            shootLabel.setText(text);
        }
        flagThing++;
        if (flagThing > 3) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new RockPaperScissorsShoot());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I may add this as to my project later, but as of now, a friend actually helped me solve this.